# How to keep an HDMI connected monitor from powering off

Tags: xubuntu, display, hdmi

I'm running Xubuntu 16.10 and I'm using it to run a "room monitor" for our call center.

When I leave for the day, all is well. When I return in the morning I have to plug in a mouse and move it around to get the screen to come back.

I did some searching and the `xset -q` and `xrandr -q` commands were mentioned.

When I try either of them I get "Can't open display". I get the same response if I try it with sudo.

I must be missing something.

--- Edit: Further details ---

The "wallboard" is a web app supplied by our VoIP provider. The computer in question is bascially running a "kiosked" view of the webpage, which is displayed on a TV connected via HDMI.

Where this gets odd(-er?) is that the web app is working just fine, as I write this.

details of `env | sort`

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
HOME=/home/caleb
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LOGNAME=caleb
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or
=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*
.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01
;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;
31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;
31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar
=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.
cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;
35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.sv
gz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;3
5:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv
=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*
.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35
:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=
00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.o
pus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/caleb
PATH=/home/caleb/bin:/home/caleb/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bi
n:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PWD=/home/caleb
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.145 23104 22
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.145 23104 192.168.1.89 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=caleb
_=/usr/bin/env
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_SESSION_ID=35
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "run a monitor". What is shown on it? The error message `Can't open display` suggests you are not running an X-session or the environment settings are incomplete or absent even.  In the same terminal where you got the error message, what does the command `env | sort` show us?

Comment: @WillemK - Fair question. I'll clarify the original question with these details.

Comment: The question is clear enough, even before the edit
What is happening here is that your terminal is becoming idle, and in order to save power your display is being disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! I figured it out, and it's a real headslapper.

The solution is to open a terminal window on the box with the monitor attached.

The commands that I mentioned above will work *just fine*, if you're **not** in a ssh session. Which I was, and so there was no "display" info to show. For those interested I got these commands from this SuperUser answer - https://superuser.com/a/1180385/426308

Answer (score 2):

Bring up your settings dialog

You may press the Ubuntu button on the top left of the Unity bar or the Windows key on your keyboard

Go to Settings

Brightness and Lock

Make required changes, the options here should be fairly self-explanatory

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "Brightness and Lock" setting in the Xfce Whisker menu. Does it have a different name?